# Переворот карты не получается

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

FlashCards

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .header {
        background-color: cadetblue;
        font-style: verdana;
        font-size: 50px;
        height: 100px;
        color: white;
    }
    .main {
        background-color: whitesmoke;
        font-style: verdana;
        font-size: 20px;
        height: 600px;
        color: green;

    }
    .footer {
        background-color: cadetblue;
        font-style: verdana;
        font-size: 50px;
        height: 200px;
        color: white;
    }
    .train-head{
        background-color: white;
        width: 600px;
        margin: auto;
    }
    .train-content {
        background-color: lightgrey;
        width: 600px;
        margin: auto;
        height: 600px;
    }
    .train-inner {
        background-color: white;
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
        margin: auto;
        position: relative;
    }
    .train-comment {
        background-color: mistyrose;
        width: 500px;
        height: 150px;
        margin: auto;
        position: relative;
    }
ul li {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-perspective: 400;
    -moz-perspective: 400;
    perspective: 400;
}

ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0s;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 0s;
}

ul li a span {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0; 
    z-index: 100;
    background: center 0 no-repeat;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    border-radius:10px;
}

ul li a.btn-main span {
    background:blue;
    color:#fff;
}

ul li a span.back {
    z-index: 90;
    background:red;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    color:#fff;
}

ul li a.reverse span.back {
    z-index: 110;
}

    </style>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
setInterval(each_frame, 25);
var position = 0;

$('#go').click(function() {
    var panel = $('.btn-main');
    if (panel.hasClass('reverse')) {
        panel.removeClass('reverse');
        position = 0;
        ampl = angle - position;
    } else {        
        panel.addClass('reverse');
        position = 180;
        ampl = angle - position;
    }
    t=0;
});


var t = 0;
var gamma = 0.3;
var ampl = 45;
var angle = 0;


function each_frame(){
    var panel = $('.btn-main');
    angle = position + Math.round(Math.exp(-gamma*t) * ampl * Math.cos(t));

    panel.css({
            'transform': 'rotateY(' + angle + 'deg)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(' + angle + 'deg)'
    });

    t += 0.2;
}

});//]]>  

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class = "header" > Welcome </div>
<div class = "main"><center> </center>

    <div class="train-head"><center>FlashCards</center></div>

    <div class="train-content"> 

        <div class="train-inner">

            <ul class="nav-buttons">
             <li><a href="#" class="btn-main"><span class="front">Front</span><span class="back">Back</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Flip!" id="go">
        </div>

        <div class="train-comment"></div>

    </div>

</div>
<div class = "footer"> </div>

</body>
</html>



    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){
    setInterval(each_frame, 25);
    var position = 0;

    $('#go').click(function() {
        var panel = $('.btn-main');
        if (panel.hasClass('reverse')) {
            panel.removeClass('reverse');
            position = 0;
            ampl = angle - position;
        } else {        
            panel.addClass('reverse');
            position = 180;
            ampl = angle - position;
        }
        t=0;
    });


    var t = 0;
    var gamma = 0.3;
    var ampl = 45;
    var angle = 0;


    function each_frame(){
        var panel = $('.btn-main');
        angle = position + Math.round(Math.exp(-gamma*t) * ampl * Math.cos(t));
        
        panel.css({
                'transform': 'rotateY(' + angle + 'deg)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(' + angle + 'deg)'
        });

        t += 0.2;
    }

    });//]]>  

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
     .header {
      background-color: cadetblue;
      font-style: verdana;
      font-size: 50px;
      height: 100px;
      color: white;
     }
     .main {
      background-color: whitesmoke;
      font-style: verdana;
      font-size: 20px;
      height: 600px;
      color: green;

     }
     .footer {
      background-color: cadetblue;
      font-style: verdana;
      font-size: 50px;
      height: 200px;
      color: white;
     }
     .train-head{
      background-color: white;
      width: 600px;
      margin: auto;
     }
     .train-content {
      background-color: lightgrey;
      width: 600px;
      margin: auto;
      height: 600px;
     }
     .train-inner {
      background-color: white;
      width: 500px;
      height: 400px;
      margin: auto;
      position: relative;
     }
     .train-comment {
      background-color: mistyrose;
      width: 500px;
      height: 150px;
      margin: auto;
      position: relative;
     }
    ul li {
        float: left;
        margin: 10px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-perspective: 400;
        -moz-perspective: 400;
        perspective: 400;
    }

    ul li a {
        display: block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0s;
        -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0s;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: transform 0s;
    }

    ul li a span {
        display: block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0; 
        z-index: 100;
        background: center 0 no-repeat;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        border-radius:10px;
    }

    ul li a.btn-main span {
        background:blue;
        color:#fff;
    }

    ul li a span.back {
        z-index: 90;
        background:red;
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        color:#fff;
    }

    ul li a.reverse span.back {
        z-index: 110;
    }
    <body>

    <div class = "header" > Welcome </div>
    <div class = "main"><center> </center>

     <div class="train-head"><center>FlashCards</center></div>

     <div class="train-content"> 
     
      <div class="train-inner">
       
       <ul class="nav-buttons">
              <li><a href="#" class="btn-main"><span class="front">Front</span><span class="back">Back</span></a></li>
          </ul>
          <br />
       <input type="submit" value="Flip!" id="go">
      </div>

      <div class="train-comment"></div>

     </div>

    </div>
    <div class = "footer"> </div>

    </body>
```